# How to keep the socket connection open on a Browser Extension minimize (Chrome/ Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket, firefox-addon

I have a web application (containing telephony controls). I wanted to convert it to a browser extension.

I have started writing a Chrome extension. I want to keep my extension running in the background (on a minimize).

My extension consumes a third-party library (for telephony controls). This library maintains a socket connection.

When I load the extension for the first time it initializes the connection and things work as expected but when I minimize the extension and try to re-open it, it went to re-initialize the library again. This causes a significant delay because there will be a lot of minimize/ maximize requests.

Is there any way to maintain the initialization/ state/ connection of my extension on minimize?

I have used `chrome.storage.local.set` to store the initialized version in local storage & `chrome.storage.local.get` to get the initialized flag. Used `chrome.runtime.onMessage` & `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` for communication between scripts.

Comment: Maintain the connection inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).

Comment: It is not possible to use the chrome.offscreen API to keep socket connection open/active in a browser extension.

The chrome.offscreen API is designed for creating headless browser windows and does not have the capability to embed third-party applications.

Comment: If your goal is ManifestV3 Chrome extension then the offscreen document is essentially the same as ManifestV2 background page, the only difference is that it can't use most of `chrome` API, so you can certainly use a socket connection and even embed third-party iframes, in which third-party apps can run. If something doesn't work for your app, describe it in more detail or add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question. If your goal is a Firefox extension, you can make the connection right in the background script.

Comment: Also, please clarify "minimizing an extension" because there's no such established term and it can mean a lot of things, especially since you use the word "open" next, which implies that the window was actually closed, not minimized.